# Our stats so far, compared to the other SE betas

Tags: discussion, statistics

When I posted [How should we promote the site?](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101/how-should-we-promote-the-site) a couple weeks ago I included some charts comparing all the different SE betas. There was a request for updated information, so I figured I would just post it separately.

---

#### Posts

[SE Posts by Site http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chxt=y,x&chds=0,7000,0,7000&chxs=1,676767,8,0,l,676767&chxr=0,0,7000|1,0,95&chco=A2C180,3D7930,22411B&chbh=a&chtt=SE+Posts+by+Site&chxl=1:|web|game|pro|food|dev|photo|stat|math|home|geo|tex|ubu|money|eng|ui|unix|word|cs|apple|rpg|bike|prg|droid&chdl=Unanswered|Questions|Answers&chd=t:214,86,33,2,13,11,36,100,21,45,13,56,16,12,2,35,74,41,93,5,5,12,120|1808,2291,773,1638,776,736,690,1355,518,512,954,1216,1001,791,278,573,612,399,698,511,254,807,402|2722,2862,1602,4055,2387,1983,1518,2261,844,1027,1476,2092,1536,1676,1074,1137,802,737,971,1893,685,5673,522&chs=600x200&cht=bvs](http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chxt=y,x&chds=0,7000,0,7000&chxs=1,676767,8,0,l,676767&chxr=0,0,7000|1,0,95&chco=A2C180,3D7930,22411B&chbh=a&chtt=SE+Posts+by+Site&chxl=1:|web|game|pro|food|dev|photo|stat|math|home|geo|tex|ubu|money|eng|ui|unix|word|cs|apple|rpg|bike|prg|droid&chdl=Unanswered|Questions|Answers&chd=t:214,86,33,2,13,11,36,100,21,45,13,56,16,12,2,35,74,41,93,5,5,12,120|1808,2291,773,1638,776,736,690,1355,518,512,954,1216,1001,791,278,573,612,399,698,511,254,807,402|2722,2862,1602,4055,2387,1983,1518,2261,844,1027,1476,2092,1536,1676,1074,1137,802,737,971,1893,685,5673,522&chs=600x200&cht=bvs)

[SE Posts by Site (normalized) http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chxt=y,x&chds=0,300,0,300&chxs=1,676767,8,0,l,676767&chxr=0,0,300|1,0,95&chco=A2C180,3D7930,22411B&chbh=a&chtt=SE+Posts+by+Site+%28normalized%29&chxl=1:|web|game|pro|food|dev|photo|stat|math|home|geo|tex|ubu|money|eng|ui|unix|word|cs|apple|rpg|bike|prg|droid&chdl=Unanswered|Questions|Answers&chd=t:2,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,2,0,0,0,9|19,28,10,20,10,10,10,20,8,8,15,21,19,15,5,12,13,9,17,13,8,32,31|28,35,20,52,32,27,22,33,12,16,24,35,29,32,23,25,18,18,25,50,21,227,40&chs=600x200&cht=bvs](http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chxt=y,x&chds=0,300,0,300&chxs=1,676767,8,0,l,676767&chxr=0,0,300|1,0,95&chco=A2C180,3D7930,22411B&chbh=a&chtt=SE+Posts+by+Site+%28normalized%29&chxl=1:|web|game|pro|food|dev|photo|stat|math|home|geo|tex|ubu|money|eng|ui|unix|word|cs|apple|rpg|bike|prg|droid&chdl=Unanswered|Questions|Answers&chd=t:2,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,2,0,0,0,9|19,28,10,20,10,10,10,20,8,8,15,21,19,15,5,12,13,9,17,13,8,32,31|28,35,20,52,32,27,22,33,12,16,24,35,29,32,23,25,18,18,25,50,21,227,40&chs=600x200&cht=bvs)

The [Programmers SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) rather destroys the curve with their 7 answers/question average, so here's the normalized chart without them (I left them out of the remaining normalized charts for the same reason):

[SE Posts by Site (normalized) without programmers.se http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chxt=y,x&chds=0,90,0,90&chxs=1,676767,8,0,l,676767&chxr=0,0,90|1,0,95&chco=A2C180,3D7930,22411B&chbh=a&chtt=SE+Posts+by+Site+%28normalized%29&chxl=1:|web|game|pro|food|dev|photo|stat|math|home|geo|tex|ubu|money|eng|ui|unix|word|cs|apple|rpg|bike|droid&chdl=Unanswered|Questions|Answers&chd=t:2,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,2,0,0,9|19,28,10,20,10,10,10,20,8,8,15,21,19,15,5,12,13,9,17,13,8,31|28,35,20,52,32,27,22,33,12,16,24,35,29,32,23,25,18,18,25,50,21,40&chs=600x200&cht=bvs](http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chxt=y,x&chds=0,90,0,90&chxs=1,676767,8,0,l,676767&chxr=0,0,90|1,0,95&chco=A2C180,3D7930,22411B&chbh=a&chtt=SE+Posts+by+Site+%28normalized%29&chxl=1:|web|game|pro|food|dev|photo|stat|math|home|geo|tex|ubu|money|eng|ui|unix|word|cs|apple|rpg|bike|droid&chdl=Unanswered|Questions|Answers&chd=t:2,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,2,0,0,9|19,28,10,20,10,10,10,20,8,8,15,21,19,15,5,12,13,9,17,13,8,31|28,35,20,52,32,27,22,33,12,16,24,35,29,32,23,25,18,18,25,50,21,40&chs=600x200&cht=bvs)

#### Votes

[SE Votes by Site http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chxt=y,x&chds=0,40000,0,40000&chxs=1,676767,8,0,l,676767&chxr=0,0,40000|1,0,95&chco=3D7930&chbh=a&chtt=SE+Votes+by+Site&chxl=1:|web|game|pro|food|dev|photo|stat|math|home|geo|tex|ubu|money|eng|ui|unix|word|cs|apple|rpg|bike|prg|droid&chdl=Votes&chd=t:22604,31779,11039,27854,17310,13325,10522,19981,5617,5714,16034,13567,11403,12222,6312,7640,4105,10185,6964,8520,4508,29100,3224&chs=600x200&cht=bvs](http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chxt=y,x&chds=0,40000,0,40000&chxs=1,676767,8,0,l,676767&chxr=0,0,40000|1,0,95&chco=3D7930&chbh=a&chtt=SE+Votes+by+Site&chxl=1:|web|game|pro|food|dev|photo|stat|math|home|geo|tex|ubu|money|eng|ui|unix|word|cs|apple|rpg|bike|prg|droid&chdl=Votes&chd=t:22604,31779,11039,27854,17310,13325,10522,19981,5617,5714,16034,13567,11403,12222,6312,7640,4105,10185,6964,8520,4508,29100,3224&chs=600x200&cht=bvs)

[SE Votes by Site (normalized) http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chxt=y,x&chds=0,400,0,400&chxs=1,676767,8,0,l,676767&chxr=0,0,400|1,0,95&chco=3D7930&chbh=a&chtt=SE+Votes+by+Site+%28normalized%29&chxl=1:|web|game|pro|food|dev|photo|stat|math|home|geo|tex|ubu|money|eng|ui|unix|word|cs|apple|rpg|bike|droid&chdl=Votes&chd=t:237,392,137,352,230,182,152,293,83,86,258,226,215,235,131,162,89,248,174,224,140,248&chs=600x200&cht=bvs](http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chxt=y,x&chds=0,400,0,400&chxs=1,676767,8,0,l,676767&chxr=0,0,400|1,0,95&chco=3D7930&chbh=a&chtt=SE+Votes+by+Site+%28normalized%29&chxl=1:|web|game|pro|food|dev|photo|stat|math|home|geo|tex|ubu|money|eng|ui|unix|word|cs|apple|rpg|bike|droid&chdl=Votes&chd=t:237,392,137,352,230,182,152,293,83,86,258,226,215,235,131,162,89,248,174,224,140,248&chs=600x200&cht=bvs)

#### Views

[SE Views by Site http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chxt=y,x&chds=0,600000,0,600000&chxs=1,676767,8,0,l,676767&chxr=0,0,600000|1,0,95&chco=3D7930&chbh=a&chtt=SE+Views+by+Site&chxl=1:|web|game|pro|food|dev|photo|stat|math|home|geo|tex|ubu|money|eng|ui|unix|word|cs|apple|rpg|bike|prg|droid&chdl=Views&chd=t:160928,508896,65392,184166,171261,74103,86953,245919,31814,56049,112055,105579,97583,82486,51622,71965,34280,129436,40354,48066,23184,258142,11649&chs=600x200&cht=bvs](http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chxt=y,x&chds=0,600000,0,600000&chxs=1,676767,8,0,l,676767&chxr=0,0,600000|1,0,95&chco=A2C180&chbh=a&chtt=SE+Views+by+Site&chxl=1:|web|game|pro|food|dev|photo|stat|math|home|geo|tex|ubu|money|eng|ui|unix|word|cs|apple|rpg|bike|prg|droid&chdl=Views&chd=t:160928,508896,65392,184166,171261,74103,86953,245919,31814,56049,112055,105579,97583,82486,51622,71965,34280,129436,40354,48066,23184,258142,11649&chs=600x200&cht=bvs)

[SE Views by Site (normalized) http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chxt=y,x&chds=0,7000,0,7000&chxs=1,676767,8,0,l,676767&chxr=0,0,7000|1,0,95&chco=3D7930&chbh=a&chtt=SE+Views+by+Site+%28normalized%29&chxl=1:|web|game|pro|food|dev|photo|stat|math|home|geo|tex|ubu|money|eng|ui|unix|word|cs|apple|rpg|bike|droid&chdl=Views&chd=t:1693,6282,817,2331,2283,1015,1260,3616,474,849,1807,1759,1841,1586,1075,1531,745,3156,1008,1264,724,896&chs=600x200&cht=bvs](http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chxt=y,x&chds=0,7000,0,7000&chxs=1,676767,8,0,l,676767&chxr=0,0,7000|1,0,95&chco=3D7930&chbh=a&chtt=SE+Views+by+Site+%28normalized%29&chxl=1:|web|game|pro|food|dev|photo|stat|math|home|geo|tex|ubu|money|eng|ui|unix|word|cs|apple|rpg|bike|droid&chdl=Views&chd=t:1693,6282,817,2331,2283,1015,1260,3616,474,849,1807,1759,1841,1586,1075,1531,745,3156,1008,1264,724,896&chs=600x200&cht=bvs)

#### Users

[SE Users by Site http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chxt=y,x&chds=0,5000,0,5000&chxs=1,676767,8,0,l,676767&chxr=0,0,5000|1,0,95&chco=3D7930&chbh=a&chtt=SE+Users+by+Site&chxl=1:|web|game|pro|food|dev|photo|stat|math|home|geo|tex|ubu|money|eng|ui|unix|word|cs|apple|rpg|bike|prg|droid&chdl=Users&chd=t:4634,3706,2075,2591,2287,1484,1407,2146,842,894,1294,2507,1358,1424,1822,2010,1045,1512,1101,667,508,3686,471&chs=600x200&cht=bvs](http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chxt=y,x&chds=0,5000,0,5000&chxs=1,676767,8,0,l,676767&chxr=0,0,5000|1,0,95&chco=3D7930&chbh=a&chtt=SE+Users+by+Site&chxl=1:|web|game|pro|food|dev|photo|stat|math|home|geo|tex|ubu|money|eng|ui|unix|word|cs|apple|rpg|bike|prg|droid&chdl=Users&chd=t:4634,3706,2075,2591,2287,1484,1407,2146,842,894,1294,2507,1358,1424,1822,2010,1045,1512,1101,667,508,3686,471&chs=600x200&cht=bvs)

[SE Users by Site (normalized) http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chxt=y,x&chds=0,50,0,50&chxs=1,676767,8,0,l,676767&chxr=0,0,50|1,0,95&chco=3D7930&chbh=a&chtt=SE+Users+by+Site+%28normalized%29&chxl=1:|web|game|pro|food|dev|photo|stat|math|home|geo|tex|ubu|money|eng|ui|unix|word|cs|apple|rpg|bike|droid&chdl=Users&chd=t:48,45,25,32,30,20,20,31,12,13,20,41,25,27,37,42,22,36,27,17,15,36&chs=600x200&cht=bvs](http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chxt=y,x&chds=0,50,0,50&chxs=1,676767,8,0,l,676767&chxr=0,0,50|1,0,95&chco=3D7930&chbh=a&chtt=SE+Users+by+Site+%28normalized%29&chxl=1:|web|game|pro|food|dev|photo|stat|math|home|geo|tex|ubu|money|eng|ui|unix|word|cs|apple|rpg|bike|droid&chdl=Users&chd=t:48,45,25,32,30,20,20,31,12,13,20,41,25,27,37,42,22,36,27,17,15,36&chs=600x200&cht=bvs)

Comment: Can I ask a silly question? What does 'normalized' mean?

Comment: @Stefan according to the old post, normalized means "accounted for age"

Comment: It's possible I completely misused the term, when I generated the charts originally I didn't intend to share them, I was just curious. It's the values from the non-normalized chart divided by the number of days the site has been in beta

Comment: Where did you get these graphs?