# Where's everybody?

Tags: discussion

Linux is about 1-2% market share (hopefully more), which is still a lot of people.
Wondered why this site doesn't seem very popular.

What other Q&A sites on Linux out there?
If I use Gentoo, should I go straight to forums.gentoo.org, or are there other good places for general Linux questions?

Comment: this question should be rather be asked on [meta](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/). And as the 'close' votes are going, it soon will be moved there

Comment: @Stefan Those comments usually are a bad idea; they may trigger the asker to make a new, duplicate question on the "right" site. That'd get you two questions there, one of which needs to be closed. It's better to just silently migrate.

Comment: mm... i hear you, and thats why I also mentioned that i would be moved. Problem is I haven't seen a mechanism that alerts the OP that the question has moved. Since OP is new to SE ( judgin from OP's reputation) OP might suspect deletion, which might make him/her feel unwelcome. just me two cents

Comment: lol @ 'i would be moved', should be 'it'

Answer (score 13, accepted):

4 reasons:

1. **Ubuntu SE** - I seriously believe a lot of our people are there, and I blame management for trying to be democratic instead of putting their foot down.
2. **ServerFault** - I see questions on there that should be here. I wonder if we can talk someone into advertising us there. I see quite a few questions on there that are small home network, permissions, things that aren't serious server admin questions, that would be, imo, better fielded here
3. **New Tech** - most unix people are hardcore oldschool, meaning mailing lists and irc, also forums.
4. **Unknown** - just in general I don't think all the unix geeks know about it. [Spread the word](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101/how-should-we-promote-the-site).

Comment: we could push for migrating questions from SF once we launch right?

Comment: @Stefan, idk, maybe some of them...

Comment: Some caller to Joel's podcast mentioned they where organising a 'bulk copy' of Erlang usenet stuff to SO. We could always try something similar here.

Answer (score 3):

This site does have relatively little daily visits, but actually 95% of questions asked are answered, so that's not really a problem. (Compare with, say, ask.debian.net, which is an *official* Q&A site. It sports a whopping [21 people who ever gave any answer...](http://ask.debian.net/badges/troubleshooter))

The best way to boost a site is to use it. Answer, ask if there's nothing to answer and spread the word.

Comment: This answer assumes this question will be migrated to Meta.

Comment: have to admit that there is only 5 not-answered questions out of the 161 question they have

Comment: For some reason I lost ownership of this answer...

Comment: http://ask.debian.net is not official, even though it's endorsed by DPL (Debian Project Leader).

Comment: unfortunately the moderators don't actually have the power to fix this...