# Rename unix.SE to opensource.SE

Tags: feature-request

Unix.SE doesn't seem very popular, and there are [many reasons for it](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/232/wheres-everybody).
But there is another thing that can be improved, and that's the name.

I believe that for many (especially young) people, "Unix" is something that is old and not used anymore. If you look at Ubuntu, they position it as an alternative to Windows, not as "better Unix".
And "Linux" is not general enough.

So, why not rename it to opensource.stackexchange.com, isn't Open Source what it's all about these days?
That way, having separate site for Ubuntu will make [even less sense](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/fork-it/).

Comment: Repost of http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/69623/149076

Comment: instead of trying to change current communities into what you want them to be, why not create a great community through the [area51 proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/create) proccess?

Comment: @Stefan because there already too many sites and audience is overly fragmented?

Comment: What im trying to say is that: This is Unix.SE, end-of-argument.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not clear on whether you're proposing to also change the scope of this site or just the name.

If you do want to change the scope so that questions like "How can I install Media Player Classic on Windows XP" become on topic (MPC being open source software), I'm strongly opposed to this. This would change the nature of this site dramatically.

If you don't propose this, I'm still opposed to the name change because the name would not be representative of what the site is about and would likely confuse many people. I mean who wouldn't expect that asking about any open source software would be on-topic on a Q&A site named "opensource"?

Comment: The original idea was about open source OS'es (Linux), and for people who use such operating systems, not just any software. Especially when for software questions we already have SuperUser. And it also seems that open source software tend to be cross-platform, but yeah, MPC is an exception.

Comment: Also probably Linux expert could answer more questions on comertial *nixes then Windows.